# Make placeholder loading responsive

Tags: reactjs, placeholder, loader

I'm using **create-content-loader** package for creating placeholder loading but can't make it responsive.
How to make svg fill parent content. I don't want to set width hardcoded 1060px. I tried with viewbox property too.

````
   <ContentLoader
      height={40}
      width={1060}
      speed={2}
      primaryColor="#d9d9d9"
      secondaryColor="#ecebeb"
    >
      <rect x="10" y="40" rx="0" ry="0" width="75" height="10" />
      <rect x="10" y="60" rx="0" ry="0" width="75" height="10" />
      <rect x="10" y="100" rx="0" ry="0" width="75" height="10" />
      <rect x="10" y="80" rx="0" ry="0" width="75" height="10" />
      <rect x="10" y="120" rx="0" ry="0" width="75" height="10" />
      <rect x="110" y="40" rx="0" ry="0" width="370" height="125" />
      <rect x="275" y="63" rx="0" ry="0" width="72" height="4" />
      <rect x="430" y="5" rx="5" ry="5" width="75" height="20" />
      <rect x="110" y="10" rx="0" ry="0" width="200" height="15" />
      <rect x="10" y="5" rx="4" ry="4" width="75" height="20" />
      <circle cx="493" cy="54" r="2" />
      <circle cx="497" cy="47" r="7" />
      <circle cx="497" cy="77" r="7" />
      <circle cx="497" cy="107" r="7" />
    </ContentLoader>```
````

Answer (score 0):

`ContentLoader` uses html5 `canvas` for rendering, so `viewbox` won't work. What I would do is:

1. add `ref` to container element (which holds `ContentLoader`).
2. get that element width by using ref
3. pass that value to the `ContentLoader` width prop.

Keep in mind that on the first render `ref.current` will be `null` or `undefined`

Update:

Also you can try to extract svg from [create-content-loader example](https://danilowoz.com/create-content-loader/) and turn it into your component. Just change svg attributes to match rect related svg props. Than set css class on svg to have these properties:

```
.responsive-svg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Svg (before you turn it into react component) might look something like this:

```
<svg
  role="img"
  width="400"
  height="160"
  aria-labelledby="loading-aria"
  viewBox="0 0 400 160"
  preserveAspectRatio="none"
>
  <title id="loading-aria">Loading...</title>
  <rect
    x="0"
    y="0"
    width="100%"
    height="100%"
    clip-path="url(#clip-path)"
    style='fill: url("#fill");'
  ></rect>
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="clip-path">
        <rect x="48" y="8" rx="3" ry="3" width="88" height="6" /> 
        <rect x="48" y="26" rx="3" ry="3" width="52" height="6" /> 
        <rect x="0" y="56" rx="3" ry="3" width="410" height="6" /> 
        <rect x="0" y="72" rx="3" ry="3" width="380" height="6" /> 
        <rect x="0" y="88" rx="3" ry="3" width="178" height="6" /> 
        <circle cx="20" cy="20" r="20" />
    </clipPath>
    <linearGradient id="fill">
      <stop
        offset="0.599964"
        stop-color="#f3f3f3"
        stop-opacity="1"
      >
        <animate
          attributeName="offset"
          values="-2; -2; 1"
          keyTimes="0; 0.25; 1"
          dur="2s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
        ></animate>
      </stop>
      <stop
        offset="1.59996"
        stop-color="#ecebeb"
        stop-opacity="1"
      >
        <animate
          attributeName="offset"
          values="-1; -1; 2"
          keyTimes="0; 0.25; 1"
          dur="2s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
        ></animate>
      </stop>
      <stop
        offset="2.59996"
        stop-color="#f3f3f3"
        stop-opacity="1"
      >
        <animate
          attributeName="offset"
          values="0; 0; 3"
          keyTimes="0; 0.25; 1"
          dur="2s"
          repeatCount="indefinite"
        ></animate>
      </stop>
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
</svg>
```

Comment: I need to make it responsive as well, so in that case, I must on every resize  get container size which I think is not so good (

Comment: Gotcha! Than approach I've suggested won't work. Even more, setting `ContentLoader` to be full width won't make each `rect` elements to scale proportionally and fit `ContentLoader`..

Comment: I tried updated version too, not working as well, now trying to  use https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-placeholder this package, hoping that will work